# I don't fully understand what app.get('/consult')

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am new to express and I still struggle with the meaning of `app.get()`.
In my HTML page, I have a button with the id=consult-button.
I gave it the following script:

```
document.getElementById("consult-button").addEventListener("click", function() {
   window.location.href = '/consulting';
      });
```

On my app.js file, on the other hand, I have:

```
app.get('/consulting', (req, res) => {
  const client = new pg.Client(config);
  client.connect();
  client.query('SELECT * FROM questionaire', (err, result) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
    res.send(result.rows);
    client.end();
  });
});
```

Can someone help me understand this? Tell me if what I am writing is right:
when the button is clicked, a url with the name "consulting" is created. then app.get call on that url and sends the results of the query in that url?

Comment: `app.get` tells the server to listen for requests to the specified URL, and when such a request is received then that code produces the server's response.

Comment: so the url is created by " window.location.href " but app.get just gets the request to execute the function

Comment: Yes, the client-side code is redirecting the user to a new URL, and the server-side code is responding to that request.  It sounds like you're essentially asking what a web server is and how it works, which is fairly broad.

Comment: _"in my html page i have button"_ ... which should be a _link_ to begin with. If you want that link to _look_ like a button, then format it accordingly. Recreating link functionality using JavaScript is really rather bad.

Comment: rtm: https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html

Comment: It's about _[routing](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html)_ in _express_.  I recommend you read about [basic routing](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/basic-routing.html).

Answer (score 0):

[image]

When the user clicks on the button on the web page, the browser is going to send an HTTP GET request to the endpoint on the server `(/consulting)`,

for example, if your website domain is **[www.example.com](http://www.example.com)**, the browser is going to send the request to **[www.example.com/consulting](http://www.example.com/consulting)**,

or if your domain is **192.168.1.50:3000** for example in case you're working on localhost for example, the website is going to send a request to **192.168.1.50:3000/consulting**.

But this piece of code doesn't only send a request to the server, it also changes the URL to **/consulting**, (ex: **[www.example.com](http://www.example.com)** becomes **[www.example.com/consulting](http://www.example.com/consulting)**).

Now when the request travels from the website (the computer of the website visitor) to the back-end server (which is express in your case), express is going to catch this request in the following ***controller*** *(it's called a controller)*

```
app.get('/consulting', (req, res) => {
  const client = new pg.Client(config);
  client.connect();
  client.query('SELECT * FROM questionaire', (err, result) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
    res.send(result.rows);
    client.end();
  });
});
```

`app.get` is the controller which catches this request and handles it because it's

`app.get('/consulting')` which matches the destination of the request.

Now this controller has a bunch of codes, it basically sends a request to the Postgres database saying **"SELECT * FROM questionaire"** *which basically means give me all the entries inside the questionaire table*.

the database responds with that, so the server (the controller) takes care of the response from the database and forwards it back to the website.

Hope this helps.

Comment: [Please post code as formatted text, not images of formatted text.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: No worries, this is a screenshot from his code, so he can know that he's the one who've written this.

Comment: Please read the reference and reconsider.

Comment: @DaveNewton ✅ because you said please